# Soundcloud widget API load method doesn't apply all visual options

Tags: soundcloud

When updating a SoundCloud widget initially embedded using `oembed` and then updating via load, for example calling `widget1.load(url, options)` does not apply all of the visual options. The visual options are applied on the initial oembed call, but the load call does not apply them.

Here are the options being sent to the method:

```
show_bpm: true,
maxheight: 166,
color: '00ace8',
theme_color: '000000',
download: false,
sharing: false,
buying: false,
font: 'Droid Sans',
enable_api: true,
show_user: true,
show_comments: false,
```

Here are screenshots of the two versions:

[image: SoundCloud screenshots]

The first using the oembed call and the second using the load call via the widget api. It appears the "color" tag is being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you included it as a query string at the end of your url.  So just put `?color=00ace8` at the end of your track's URL, like this:

```
url = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/90319611?color=00ace8'

widget.load(url,options)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `color` option is not an accepted parameter for the `load(url,options)` method.  `options` parameters are different for `oembed` and `load` methods.

You can see the different parameters following the links: [oEmbed params](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#oembed) and [Widget.load params](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#params)